# Iframe post Message, passing variable

Tags: javascript, post, iframe

How to pass variable through postMessage. I can call a parent function like this:

```
function parent_goTopPage() {
  window.parent.postMessage({"func": "goTopPage"}, "*");
}
```

But didn't find a way to pass variable in the function. For example the variable myvar in the parent function checkVar:

```
function checkVar(myvar) {
  alert(myvar);
}
```

The following javascript does not work:

```
function parent_checkVar(myvar) {
  window.parent.postMessage({"func": "checkVar(" + myvar + "}, "*");
}
```

**EDIT**

I finally realised that I already had this possibility with the "message" option `window[data.func].call(null, data.message);`

On the parent window:

```
function checkVar(myvar) {
  alert(myvar);
}

window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);

function onMessage(event) {
  // Check sender origin to be trusted
  if (event.origin !== "https://example.com") {
     alert("Error Cross-origin onMessage.");
     return;
  };
   var data = event.data;
   if (typeof(window[data.func]) == "function") {
     window[data.func].call(null, data.message);
  }
}
```

Inside the iframe:

```
function parent_checkVar(myvar) {
   window.parent.postMessage({"func": "checkVar", "message":myvar}, "*");
}
parent_checkVar(3);
```

The choice of "message" was not very clear to me, I changed it to var1 only on (parent windows):

```
window[data.func].call(null, data.var1);
```

And on (iframe):

```
window.parent.postMessage({"func": "checkVar", "var1":myvar}, "*");
```

With the choice of "message" there was like a misunderstanding with on this line (parent window) `window.addEventListener("message", onMessage, false);`. `"message"` must stay with this name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the JavaScript you posted has a malformed object. It should be `{"func": "checkVar(" + myvar + ")"}`

Second, although you didn't post it, I'm almost certain you're wanting to use `eval()` for `checkVar(myVar)`. Instead of doing that, you can create an object and assign a function with key name of "checkVar". When you do this, you can pass the checkVar variable separately and call the function using the object. You can see the example below:

Pass an extra key/value with your object. I added `"thisvar":myvar`.

```js
window.parent.postMessage({"func": "checkVar", "thisvar":myvar}, "*");
```

On your listener, you create an object with your function inside of it.

```js
var postFunctions = {
  'checkVar': function(myvar) {window.alert(myvar);}
}
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // checks if the function "checkVar" exists inside the "postFunctions" object
  if (postFunctions[event.data.func]) {
    // if it does exist, call that function and pass the variable as an argument
    postFunctions[event.data.func](event.data.thisvar);
  }
});
```

Comment: I had taken this code from an example and didn't understand everything, but with your code I finally realised that I already had this possibility with the "message" option `window[data.func].call(null, data.message);`